# SSRS - Error for Users when loading reports

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, http-status-code-504

I am wondering if anyone would be able to assist with an issue some users are having when running reports.

When I log onto our report server as the administrator account , the reports are generating fine without any issues.

However , when users log on that have just browser permissions they are encountering this error when generating a report

[image]

I can see that this is a timeout issue when running reports , and have tried setting the permission on both the report and site level to run indefinitely with no timeout but this issue still persists.

Anyone got any idea what may be causing this ?

Thanks

Arran

Comment: Check the datasource credentials. If it's using windows authentication then check the users have access to the datasource.

Comment: Hi @AlanSchofield , just checked and the data source credentials are using SQL Username and Password

Comment: Did you check this on the server or in Visual Studio (or Report Builder)? It it's using SQL Credentials then I guess that should be OK. What happens if you log onto a user's PC using admin credentials (or launch the browser with the same admin credentials) and run the report ? I'm not sure if I can help much but thought I would at least get you gathering evidence that you can update your question with. Hopefully somebody with more security knowledge than me can help

Comment: Thanks @AlanSchofield , I checked this on the report server , it doesn't seem to be an issue with a specific report , but all reports. Odd that I can access through the admin account. I have tried granting admin permission to the user to see if that allows them to run the report.